# Подскажите что в коде не так?

Tags: php

помогите разобраться с кодом

```
class Exception

    {

        protected $message="Unknown exception";

        protected $code=0;

        protected $file;

        protected $line;

        public function __construct($message=null, $code=0);

        public final function getMessage();

        public final function getCode();

        public final function getFile();

        public final function getLine();

        public final function getTrace();

        public final function getTraceAsString();

        public function __toString();

}
```

Comment: Проверяю свои экстрасенсорные способности: у вас наверное не получается создать экземпляр этого класса, да?

Comment: нет просто это код из учебника и он почему-та выдаёт ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Подскажите что в коде не так?

У меня что-то сломалось, скажите мне скорее что.

Вижу следующие проблемы:

1. Класс Exception определен в PHP, поэтому заново объявить его в корневом неймспейсе не получится
2. Класс не отнаследован от \Exception, а потому не будет ловиться с помощью try/catch
3. Будучи отнаследованным от \Exception, класс попытается переопределить final методы, за что весь скрипт будет благополучно забанен интерпретатором.